# (Unity) How to prevent MonoBehavior Awake() function overriding in children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Is it possible to disable the option to override MonoBehavior    functions like Start(), Awake(), Update(), etc... in children class?**

The reason behind this is, that when multiple people work on Unity project, someone unaware of this problem could disable important initialization that is defined in parent which could cause unwanted behavior that is hard to debug.

It seems to me that this goes against principles of OOP since you can mess a lot of things on other places. You wont even see a warning in Visual Studio, when trying to do this.

```
public class A: MonoBehavior
{
  void Awake()
  {
    // Do some stuff
  }
}

public class B: A
{
  void Awake()
  {
    // This actually overrides stuff that Awake() does in parent class
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is something that you can disable, but I am fairly certain most IDE's will give you a warning that you're overriding a method here since you're not using the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is simple and adheres to the principles of OOP.
Any class you think could have children in the future, define in it stubs

```
protected virtual void Awake() {}
protected virtual void Start() {}
protected virtual void OnEnable() {}
```

...list goes on.

Now if someone to use any of the callbacks in a child without 'overriding' the IDE will certainly notify them that there is a base implmentation of the callback.

Comment: Oh thank you, now it at least gives a warning in IDE. Though I am a beginner programmer, it still seems to me a bit flawed (since you now rely on IDE implementation. Ideal would be, if the override keyword was mandatory). But I guess there isnt a better solution to this problem so I mark this as accepted.

Comment: @Colp The override is never *required* as you always can go around it using the `new` keyword. Additionally it is also never implicit that the patent method gets actually called unless you explicitly call `base.Awake();` in your override one.

Comment: I agree with @derHugo , this is the best solution, but it's insufficient. What if someone overrides and doesn't call base?

Answer (score 1):

I think sealing the `Awake()` method from your `class A` should be what you are looking for:

```
public class A: MonoBehavior
{
  public sealed override void Awake()
  {
    // Do some stuff
  }
}
```

Now when you try to override this method in your `class B` it will not only give an IDE warning but it will not compile.

Comment: I just quickly tried it and it says "There is no suitable method to override"

Comment: Remove the `override` .. `MonoBehaviour` itself doesn't implement `Awake`

Comment: lolThis does not work at all, dude, test the crap you're answering before doing it